# How to use the -t option of Unix command look

Tags: utilities

I'm learning the `look` utility and I don't understand the meaning of the `-t` option.

Can someone show me some examples of it?

I read the `man` page, but still don't know what it exactly means.

Comment: If you'd actually look at the [man page](http://ss64.com/bash/look.html), you'd see that the option `-t` is to ignore the case when matching.

Comment: Actually `-f` is ignore case; `-t` specifies a termination character

Comment: @Paul I did read the man page. But still didn't get what it actually means. That's why I ask for examples.

Comment: @mitnk: not really a programming question - it will probably be moved to http://superuser.com shortly - but the man page is pretty clear - what part don't you understand ?

Comment: @Paul Thank you for your comments. I just found what it means. The part I don't understand is English sentence I guess ;) Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: The examples I wanted is like "look -t i iz" VS "look iz". Thx all.

Comment: @Paul: it seems I should put on more glasses when responding to questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why that option would be useful. However here's an example:

```
$ look -df uncle /usr/share/lib/dict/words
uncle
$ look -df -tc uncle /usr/share/lib/dict/words
unchristian
uncle
uncouth
unction
```

I suppose it's to give you a mechanism to look up "similar" words if you don't have complete control over the lookup-string.